# mongodb: how to use variable as operator

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

What I'm trying to achieve is the following:

```
let validations = [
    {
        "label": "kpis.avgLatency",
        "program":"ping-test",
        "multiple":false,
        "conditions" :[
            {
                "operator" : "$gt",
                "value": NumberInt(-107)
            },
            {
                "operator" : "$lt",
                "value": NumberInt(0)
            }
        ]
    }
]
validations.map((item) => {
    let test = db.task.aggregate([
      {$addFields: {validation: item}},
      {$match: { program: item.program}},
      {$project:{
        validation2: {
          $map: {
            input: item.conditions,
            as: "val",
            in: { $cond:{ if: { $lt: ['$validation.label', '$$val.value'] } , then: true, else: false} }
        }}
    }}
    ,
    ]).toArray();

    print(test);
})
```

This is working as expected, but what I need to do is, instead of the `$lt` operator, use the operator of my `items.condition`, something like this:

```
in: { $cond:{ if: { '$$val.operator': ['$validation.label', '$$val.value'] } , then: true, else: false} }
```

That's exactly what I've tried, but is not working. Is there any way to achieve that?

It's easy to use vars as values, but I don't know how to use it as an operator.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with such an option, but you can bypass it by using branches (as the number of relevant operators is limited). Not the most elegant way of doing things though.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {$addFields: {validation: {label: 7}}},
  {$project: {
      validation2: {
        $map: {
          input: "$conditions",
          as: "val",
          in: {$switch: {
              branches: [
                {
                  case: {$eq: ["$val.operator", "$gt"]},
                  then: {$cond: {
                      if: {$gt: ["$validation.label", "$$val.value"]},
                      then: true,
                      else: false
                  }}
                },
                {
                  case: {$eq: ["$val.operator", "$lt"]},
                  then: {$cond: {
                      if: {$lt: ["$validation.label", "$$val.value"]},
                      then: true,
                      else: false
                  }}
                },
                //...
              ]
          }}
        }
      }
  }}
])
```

See how it works on the [playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Gp_7FW6N1Zc)